# Strange timestamp bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why is nickyt’s answer to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21894/1512) dated in november 2010, while the question itself is dated in december 2011?

The question:

[image]

And the answer:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens when we merge questions, specifically [In GMail, is it possible to reverse "always display images from" decisions?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9779/in-gmail-is-it-possible-to-reverse-always-display-images-from-decisions) from 2010.

Comment: Ah, OK, got it. Thanks!